# C# Timer refuses to stop ticking

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have been scratching my head all day on this one and it is infuriating me, is there any obvious problems with this that I do not know about ?

Here is the code:

```
private Timer _timer = null;
private EventHandler ev = null;
private void startAnimatingPicStatus()
{
     Console.WriteLine("    | STARTING ANIMATION");
     _timer = new Timer();
     _timer.Interval = 100;
     ev = new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
     _timer.Tick += ev;
     _timer.Start();
 }
 private int animationPosition = 0;
 private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("    | ANIMATING ANIMATION");
     animationPosition++;
     if (animationPosition == 4) animationPosition = 1;
     Dictionary<int, Image> images = new Dictionary<int, Image>();
     images[1] = myproject.Properties.Resources.animateimage_1;
     images[2] = myproject.Properties.Resources.animateimage_2;
     images[3] = myproject.Properties.Resources.animateimage_3;

     picStatus.Image = images[animationPosition];
 }

 private void stopAnimatingPicStatusIfAnimatingAndSetToComplete()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("    | STOPPING ANIMATION");
     _timer.Tick -= ev;
     _timer.Dispose();
     picStatus.Image = nofolder.Properties.Resources.tfolderg;            
  }
```

this is the debug I would expect:

```
| STARTING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| STOPPING ANIMATION
```

but this is what I get:

```
| STARTING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| STOPPING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
| ANIMATING ANIMATION
```

the good news is that it does seem to stop the animation. the bad news is it is only *sometimes* and it is random but seems to happen 50% of the time - 50% of the time the animation stops and about 50% of the time it just spins animating even though it *should* have stopped

**EDIT>SOLUTION** I added `if (ev != null) _timer.Tick -= ev;` inside `startAnimatingPicStatus()` right before the line that says `ev = new EventHandler(timer_Tick);` and this seems to have fixed it

Comment: where is `stopAnimatingPicStatusIfAnimatingAndSetToComplete` being called?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, ever call `startAnimatingPicStatus` more than once?

Comment: Try adding _timer.Stop(); before you dispose your timer.

Comment: actually, it does potentially sometimes call `startAnimatingPicStatus()` twice, before the stop, (this is by design) is there any bullet proof way to remove all tick events? @Chuck yes I did, I also set it to null (the whole object) it makes no difference

Comment: Not declare `_timer` and don't subscribe to `Tick` inside start, do it in the class constructor instead, only call `_timer.Start` in the method (also don't dispose the timer anymore in Stop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop your timer, have you tried to use the Change method, just like :

```
myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
```

More information here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I did something similar I added `if (ev != null) _timer.Tick -= ev;` right before I put `_timer.Interval = 100;` and I think it fixed it